# How do I use backbone model events in views?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using thedersen's Backbone.validation plugin to provide validation.

The validation itself works so far and gets executed when I submit the form. I only don't success about letting the view listen on validation errors.

The howto says that you can listen on validation events with:

```
model.bind('validated:invalid', function(model, attrs) {
   // do something
});
```

Source: http://thedersen.com/backbone.validation/#events/validated

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', "models/security/user", 'text!templates/security/registration.html'], function($, _, Backbone, SecurityUserModel, Template){

    var SecurityRegistrationView;

    SecurityRegistrationView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.model = new SecurityUserModel();
            this.render();
            Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
        },
        render: function(){
            $(this.el).append(Template);
        },
        events: {
            "submit form": "submit"
            , "validated:valid": "valid"
            , "validated:invalid": "invalid"
        },
        submit: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var username, email, password;
            username = $("#_user_username").val();
            email = $("#_user_email").val();
            password = $("#_user_password").val();

            this.model.set('username', username);
            this.model.set('email', email);
            this.model.set('password', password);

            this.model.validate();

            console.log(this.model.validate());
        },
        invalid: function(){
            $("input").addClass("inputError");
            alert(" ");
        },
        valid: function(){
            alert(" ");
            this.model.save(function(){
                // server validation callback...
            });
        }

    });

    return SecurityRegistrationView;
});
```

So how can I use the model related event in a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events `validated:valid` and `validated:invalid` are not DOM-events, but Backbone events. The `Backbone.View` events hash is meant for handling DOM-events ([source](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)) whereas the `model.bind` is used to tap onto events triggered by the particular model.

So remove these lines from the events-hash:

```
events: {
  "submit form": "submit", // LEAVE THIS AS IT IS A DOM EVENT
  "validated:valid": "valid", // REMOVE THIS
  "validated:invalid": "invalid" // REMOVE THIS
}
```

and add this to your initialize function

```
initialize: function(){
  this.model = new SecurityUserModel();
  this.render();
  Backbone.Validation.bind(this);

  this.model.bind('validated:valid', this.valid); // NEW
  this.model.bind('validated:invalid', this.invalid); // NEW
}
```

Now you are tapping into the model events the correct way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, that is already the second time today! Thank you ;). I will now just have to look how I can hook the validation process so I get the right input form element to add the error class

Comment: Also note that as of Backbone 0.9.9 all Backbone views have a method `listenTo` and `stopListening` you can call to automatically bind to the events on the object.  The first parameter is the object to listen to (any object extended with Backbone.Events).  Views will automatically unsubscribe when they are `remove`ed.